# Spring Log for Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, log4j, log4j2

I have a rest controller contains many methods

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/test")
public class TestRestController {

   ...... 100 methods (GET, POST, PATCH, etc)
}
```

How can I know which method is being accessed without using `print` in each method? 
Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: Are you specifically trying to limit it to this class only, or is logging all of the calls okay? (Also note that _even for "test"_ a class with this many methods is _nuts_; break them apart.)

Comment: I had answered a question to get details of the controller method using spring AOP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59743940/4214241)

Comment: Will it work on @Controller?

Comment: @BunthaiDeng Yes , you need to modify the code accordingly. Your question is for RestController , right?

Comment: it was just an additional question. Thank you, I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;    

@Aspect
public class SpringAspect {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringAspect.class);

    @Before("execution(* sample.package.path.TestRestController.*(..))")
    public void executedMethodsLogger(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        LOG.info("[ Executed method {} ]", joinPoint.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can use AOP tactics noted in the other answers to log the methods, there are better approaches if all you want to do is log all of the requests and responses for the endpoints those methods implement. There are a couple ways this can be done: Use Spring's CommonRequestLoggingFilter or write your own HandlerInterceptor. Here is a nice [article](https://frandorado.github.io/spring/2018/11/15/log-request-response-with-body-spring.html) on the first two options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring AOP:

```
package com.example;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class ExampleAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.example.TestRestController(..)")
    public void log(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Executing :" + joinPoint.toString());
    }
}
```