# Read RequestMapping annotation value

Tags: java, spring, request-mapping

To be able to do stats per endpoint, I want to be able to get the @RequestMapping annotation value, the parameterized version. My monitoring tool otherwise will consider different ids as different urls:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{customerId}/items/{itemId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<ItemDetailsDto> getItemById(
      @PathVariable(value = "customerId") int customerId
      @PathVariable(value = "itemId") int itemId)
      throws Exception
  {
    //do stuff

    //I want this to be "/customers/{customerId}/items/{itemId}"
    //,not "/customers/15988/items/85"
    String s = ????
  }
```

How can I grab `/customers/{customerId}/items/{itemId}` at runtime? 
My tool allows me to intercept methods and capture its parameters, so I could also monitor a specific method in the Spring framework to catch the setting or getting of something for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Java` reflection to do so, you just need to do like this:

```
String s= this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getItemById", int.class, int.class).getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value();
```

For the `getDeclaredMethod` the first parameter is the name of method and the other parameters are the parameters' types of that method.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will be

```
private static final String URI_GET_ITEM_BY_ID ="/customers/{customerId}/items/{itemId}";

@RequestMapping(value = URI_GET_ITEM_BY_ID, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<ItemDetailsDto> getItemById(
      @PathVariable(value = "customerId") int customerId
      @PathVariable(value = "itemId") int itemId)
      throws Exception
  {
    //do stuff

    // Use URI_GET_ITEM_BY_ID

  }
```

**Update 1:**

Assuming the controller is annotated with `@RestController`

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

      @RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{customerId}/items/{itemId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<ItemDetailsDto> getItemById(
      @PathVariable(value = "customerId") int customerId
      @PathVariable(value = "itemId") int itemId)
      throws Exception
  {
    //do stuff

    //I want this to be "/customers/{customerId}/items/{itemId}"
    //,not "/customers/15988/items/85"
    String s = ????
  }

}
```

following `Aspect` can be used to get the URI path without altering the controller methods.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class RestControllerAspect {

    @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController) && within(rg.boot.web.controller.*)")
    public void isRestController() {

    }

    @Before("isRestController()")
    public void handlePost(JoinPoint point) {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) point.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();

        // controller method annotations of type @RequestMapping
        RequestMapping[] reqMappingAnnotations = method
                .getAnnotationsByType(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.class);
        for (RequestMapping annotation : reqMappingAnnotations) {
            System.out.println(annotation.toString());
            for(String val : annotation.value()) {
                System.out.println(val);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This would print

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping(path=[], headers=[], method=[GET], name=, produces=[application/json], params=[], value=[/customers/{customerId}/items/{itemId}], consumes=[])
/customers/{customerId}/items/{itemId}
```

for a request to URI : `/customers/1234/items/5678`

**Update 2:**

Another way is to import

```
import static org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
```

and get the path using the following code

```
 RequestAttributes reqAttributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(); 
 String s = reqAttributes.getAttribute(BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE, 0);
```

This is adapted from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60167173/4214241) to another question.

Comment: Yeah that's the simplest solution, but I have over 200 controller methods and I'm trying to find a single way to get them all at runtime instead of altering my 200 methods.

Comment: Ah!! Spring AOP then ? I have a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59743940/4214241)